# Access android app port directly on mobile network

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to access an app port on android directly through mobile network. I checked my public ip from my mobile internet provider, but couldn't see it at the os level(using command ifconfig). The ip mentioned there was different on interface rmnet0. Even i couldn't find the IP in the kernel routing table. Is there another layer of routing implemented automatically by the kernel...??.Or has the network provider implemented NATing and i am recieving some private IP address...??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the mobile network operators are using NATing. The IP i am getting is a private one. So the answer would be "not possible as of now". May be possible when ipv6 becomes popular.